# problem with laravel eloquent on negative decimal

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, geolocation

I am new at laravel.

I am using this controller to find all location in map view with sw and ne that worked fine when sw and ne is positive decimal, but when sw and ne is negative queryBuilder returns nothing. When query is executed in mysql, returns correct result.

Can anyone help me to find what I am doing wrong. This is my code:

```
$lat_a = (float)\request('sw_lat');
$lat_b = (float)\request('ne_lat');
$lng_a = (float)\request('sw_lng');
$lng_b = (float)\request('ne_lng');
$data = Location::where(function ($q) use ($lat_a, $lat_b) {
    $q->WhereRaw('(?<? AND location_lat>=? AND location_lat<=?)', [$lat_a, $lat_b, $lat_a, $lat_b])
        ->orWhereRaw('(?<? AND location_lat>=? AND location_lat<=?)', [$lat_b, $lat_a, $lat_b, $lat_a]);
})->where(function ($q) use ($lng_a, $lng_b) {
    $q->WhereRaw('(?<? AND location_lng>=? AND location_lng<=?)', [$lng_a, $lng_b, $lng_a, $lng_b])
        ->orWhereRaw('(?<? AND location_lng>=? AND location_lng<=?)', [$lng_b, $lng_a, $lng_b, $lng_a]);
})->get();
```

and my table structure :

```
$table->decimal(\App\Location::COLUMN_LOCATION_LAT,10,8);
$table->decimal(\App\Location::COLUMN_LOCATION_LNG,11,8);
```

and the query log

```
rray:1 [
0 => array:3 [
 "query" => "select * from `locations` where ((?<? AND location_lat>=? AND location_lat<=?) or (?<? AND location_lat>=? AND location_lat<=?)) and ((?<? AND location_lng>=? AND location_lng<=?) or (?<? AND location_lng>=? AND location_lng<=?)) and `locations`.`deleted_at` is null"
 "bindings" => array:16 [
   0 => 41.84487754
   1 => 41.91938078
   2 => 41.84487754
   3 => 41.91938078
   4 => 41.91938078
   5 => 41.84487754
   6 => 41.91938078
   7 => 41.84487754
   8 => -87.67727337
   9 => -87.59382214
   10 => -87.67727337
   11 => -87.59382214
   12 => -87.59382214
   13 => -87.67727337
   14 => -87.59382214
   15 => -87.67727337
 ]
 "time" => 844.8
]
]
```

Comment: Can you please show the raw sql query. using 
DB::enableQueryLog(); and dd(DB::getQueryLog());  function?

Comment: @sachinkumar queryLog was attached

Comment: I hope the query treated the value as float not the string for comparisons.

Comment: @SachinKumar how can sure that?

Comment: As queryLog shows. Did you check by running the raw SQL query?